# I use the glsl syntax highlighting file, it works the first time I load a shader, after that, no highlight, why?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've a project where I work on OpenGL Shaders.

I downloaded the [glsl syntax file](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1002) and installed it on my computer (a personal folder) and then added the following auto-load line to my `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPost   *.shader,*.frag,*.vert,*.fp,*.vp,*.glsl   so $HOME/vim/glsl.vim
```

When I first load one of my '*.shader' file, I get the syntax highlighting as expect. The second time (i.e. say I loaded two files, I do `:n` and then `:N`), the highlighting is non-existent.

The syntax variable is properly set, `syntax=glsl`, but the text is just plain black on white.

The `glsl.vim` file has just two things that could cause a problem:

```
" near the start
if exists("b:current_syntax") && b:current_syntax == "glsl"
  finish
endif

...

" near the end
if !exists("b:current_syntax")
  let b:current_syntax = "glsl"
endif
```

I tried to remove the  `&& b:current_syntax == "glsl"`, because other syntax files do not have that. No difference.

Then I tried to remove the `if !exists("b:current_syntax")` near the end, and again, no difference.

All my other syntax files work as expected, so I'm not too sure why this one would have such a problem. Everything get colors (my .h and .cpp files, CMakeLists.txt, .sh, etc.) except those `*.shader` files outside of the first load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I downloaded the glsl syntax file and installed it on my computer (a personal folder)

Where did you install the syntax file?  Make sure it's located in your `~/.vim/syntax/` directory.

> and then added the following auto-load line to my .vimrc:

The `:source` command is wrong in this context:

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPost   *.shader,*.frag,*.vert,*.fp,*.vp,*.glsl   so $HOME/vim/glsl.vim
                                                                      ^-------------------^
                                                                                ✘
```

It should be a `:setfiletype` command:

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPost   *.shader,*.frag,*.vert,*.fp,*.vp,*.glsl   setf glsl
                                                                      ^-------^
                                                                          ✔
```

Have a look at the [`$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/5b8cabfef7c3707f3e53e13844d90e5a217e1e84/runtime/filetype.vim#L1472-L1473) file.

Comment: Great! That works! I guess it's time for me to upgrade my `.vimrc`... I just did a copy/paste from my other entries in that file and I thought it was working, but maybe not.